# HTAccess Rewrite Needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite any url on my domain that starts with **/club/***anyPage* to /page/club/*anyPage*.

For this, I believe I can use the following command:

```
RewriteRule ^club/([^/]*)$ /page/club/$1 [NC]
```

Also, if the physical page does not exist I want it conditionally rewritten like so:

> **/club/$1** to **/page/club/club.php?title=$1**

So in this case if the user enters in mysite.com/club/New_Club they should actually be viewing /page/club/club.php?title=New_Club

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original rules seems to work OK for it's job, but to encorporate the second requirement, something like this should do the job...

```
# do first rule if not file/directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^club/([^/]*)$ /page/club/club.php?title=$1 [NC]
# do second rule if not file/directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^club/([^/]*)$ /page/club/$1 [NC]
```

or depending on other rules...

```
# prevent requests for real files / directories from rewritting at all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^club/([^/]*)$ /page/club/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^club/([^/]*)$ /page/club/club.php?title=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Actually, this works for the second case but not when the file actually exists.  So /club/realPage redirects to /page/club/club.php?title=realPage

Comment: The first two lines here should have been RewriteCond's not RewriteRules, you would also need to duplicated them for the second rule, or refactor.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but could you edit this post to show what you mean by duplicating for the second rule?